# Reinforcement Learning for Continuous State Spaces with Discrete Actions (in NetLogo)

Tags: algorithm, netlogo, reinforcement-learning

For anybody unfamiliar, NetLogo is an agent-based modeling language. In this case the agents are simulating organisms in a dynamic environment where they search for energy. The energy moves unpredictably but diffuses over time so that foragers can find the source by going "uphill". (I'm simplifying slightly, the agents also socialize and reproduce, but if we can find a good algorithm for eating and moving then it should generalize)

The goal is for agents to maximize their energy using two actions: move N/S/E/W, and eat. The agents have access to some information: the energy level on surrounding locations and their own energy, all continuous variables. The agents can't have full explicit knowledge of their past or the world, which limits the use of most traditional RL algorithms. They can have implicit knowledge (so for example a neural network with weights that are adapted over time is okay).

My intuition was that a neural network could solve this and I implemented one successfully... But I simply ran the simulation a few thousand times to optimize the weights. This (1) doesn't guarantee convergence, and (2) is probably far from optimal/efficient.

Any ideas for how to go about learning in this world? Either a better reinforcement learning approach or an algorithm for learning the neural network weights would be great. I have gone through a lot of literature recently trying to find a solution and each algorithm I find ends up having one or two issues that preclude their use. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why can't agents have full knowledge of their past? There is nothing stopping you from creating a list as a memory, and simply adding to it each tick. Also, have you looked at Behaviour Search at http://www.behaviorsearch.org/ - it's not reinforcement learning but does implement optimisation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Since your environment is continuous, standard algorithms such as [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) or [SARSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-Action-Reward-State-Action) aren't directly applicable -- they expect a discrete environment state. However, your actions are discrete and that might be useful.

One possibility is to use some Bayesian approach in order to estimate the world state and apply it to [Reinforcement Learning with function approximation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.7833&rep=rep1&type=pdf). In fact, that's what I did in my undergraduate thesis, in which the state was estimated via [Bayesian Programming](http://www.sbgames.org/sbgames2015/anaispdf/computacao-short/147936.pdf).